# Wrong when scroll listview with adapter

Tags: android, listview, scroll

(Sorry I'm not good at English)
I haved created a custom BaseAdapter to show my data from sqlite to a ListView.
Now I can see list but when i scroll listview quickly, rows are view oddly. I can't understand this. And one more strange point is that, if i have 5 data row, getView run 5 time but only first 4 row can be show. I use log and i see 5 time "return view;" clearly.

Here are my adapter code:

```
public class LocalRankAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static final String FIELD1 = "time";
private static final String FIELD2 = "name";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "rank";
private static final String FIELD_ORDER = "time";

private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
private Cursor mCursor;
private Context mContext;
private int timeColIndex;
private int nameColIndex;
private int index;
private int length;
public static float recent_time=0;
public static String recent_playerName="";

public LocalRankAdapter(Context context, DataBaseHelper mdbHelper) {
    mContext=context;
    dbHelper=mdbHelper;

    // get data from database
    mCursor = dbHelper.getData(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { FIELD1, FIELD2 }, FIELD1 + " !=0 ", FIELD_ORDER + " ASC");
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    length=mCursor.getCount();

    timeColIndex=mCursor.getColumnIndex(FIELD1);
    nameColIndex=mCursor.getColumnIndex(FIELD2);

    index=1;
}

public static void insertData(DataBaseHelper dbHelper, float currentTime, String name) {
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(FIELD1, currentTime);
    cv.put(FIELD2, name);
    dbHelper.insertData(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {FIELD1, FIELD2}, cv);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return length-1;
}

@Override
public View getView(int id, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    View v=convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v=convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        TextView rankNumber=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtRank);
        TextView time=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
        TextView playerName=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtPlayerName);

        String timeStr=mCursor.getString(timeColIndex);
        String playerNameStr=mCursor.getString(nameColIndex);

        if(Float.parseFloat(timeStr)==(recent_time/1000f) && playerNameStr.equals(recent_playerName)) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.item_bg_recent));
            rankNumber.setText(String.valueOf(index++)+" (Your)");
        } else rankNumber.setText(String.valueOf(index++));
        time.setText(timeStr);
        playerName.setText(playerNameStr);
        mCursor.moveToNext();
        return v;           
    }
    return v;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int id) {
    return id;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

public static void setModeView(int mtime, String mplayerName) {
    recent_time=mtime;
    recent_playerName=mplayerName;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you change your query

```
String getData = "SELECT " + FIELD1 + "," + FIELD2 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
 Cursor cursor;
   cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(getData, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

      //String  cursor.getColumnIndex(FIELD1);
      int id = cursor.getInt(1);
      String name = cursor.getString(0);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see one possible problem here:

```
@Override  
public int getCount() {
    return length-1;
}
```

You should write `return length;` because `length=mCursor.getCount()`

Another issue that you use cursor inside getView and just do moveNext on it.
I think it is not good idea because fetching data isn't quick process. So it cause lags on scrolling. Try to read complete dataset to internal list of structures and use it in `getView`.

Comment: Thanks, i use length-1 because of issue that i have told. The last view is not showed, and i do "-1" to not view it (if not force close). And i think you are right, i should get data from out of getview(). I will try it.